# Linq select statement not working after grouping

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, group-by, asp.net-core-3.1

I am getting data from multiple tables by joining and I want to group data on basis of date but after group by the statement, I'm getting an error to select all entities against a date.

```
var query = from record in _entityRepository.GetAll().Where(x => x.DateRecord > DateTime.UtcNow.Date)
            join job in _jobRepository.GetAll() on record.Id equals job.Id
                into g1
            from job in g1.DefaultIfEmpty()
            join punchList in _punchListRepository.GetAll() on record.Id equals punchList.Id
                into g2 from punchList in g2.DefaultIfEmpty()
            join punchJob in _jobRepository.GetAll() on punchList != null ? -1 : punchList.JobId equals punchJob.Id
                into g4 from punchJob in g4.DefaultIfEmpty()
            group new {record, job, punchList, punchJob} by new{ record.DateRecord}
            into g3
            select new
            {
                Date = g3.Key,
                job= g3.Select(x=>x.job),
                punchList= g3.Select(x=>x.punchList)

            };
```

And I also have tried **ToList()** in select statement but it did not work.

Comment: What is the error message exactly?

Comment: @BashirMomen Error is not much clear. but this is the error"could not be translated. Either rewrite the query in a form that can be translated, or switch to client evaluation explicitly by inserting a call to either AsEnumerable(), AsAsyncEnumerable(), ToList(), or ToListAsync(). See https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=2101038 for more information."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We need to split the query into two parts because group by clause is not fully converted into SQL so in my case I want one-month data so below is my code snipet.

```
var query = from record in _entityRepository.GetAll().Where(x =>
                x.DateRecord > DateTime.UtcNow.Date && x.DateRecord <= DateTime.UtcNow.Date.AddMonths(1))
            join job in _jobRepository.GetAll() on record.Id equals job.Id
                into g1
            from job in g1.DefaultIfEmpty()
            join punchList in _punchListRepository.GetAll() on record.Id equals punchList.Id
                into g2
            from punchList in g2.DefaultIfEmpty()
            join punchJob in _jobRepository.GetAll() on punchList != null ? -1 : punchList.JobId equals punchJob.Id
                into g4
            from punchJob in g4.DefaultIfEmpty()
            select new {record, job, punchList,punchJob};

var queryResult = await query.ToListAsync();
var result = queryResult.GroupBy(x => x.record.DateRecord)
       .Select(o => new
       {
           Date = o.Key,
           job = o.Select(x => x.job ?? new Job()).ToList(),
           punchList = o.Select(x => x.punchList ?? new PunchList()).ToList()

       });
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var entityRepository=_entityRepository.GetAll().Where(x => x.DateRecord > DateTime.UtcNow.Date).ToList();
var jobRepository=_jobRepository.GetAll().ToList();;
var punchListRepository=_punchListRepository.GetAll().ToList();;


var query = from record in entityRepository
            
            join job in jobRepository on record.Id equals job.Id into g1
            from job in g1.DefaultIfEmpty()
            
            join punchList in punchListRepository on record.Id equals punchList.Id into g2 
            from punchList in g2.DefaultIfEmpty()
            
            join punchJob in jobRepository on punchList != null ? -1 : punchList.JobId equals punchJob.Id into g4 
            from punchJob in g4.DefaultIfEmpty()
            
            group new {record, job, punchList, punchJob} by new{ record.DateRecord} into g3
            select new
            {
                Date = g3.Key,
                job= g3.Select(x=>x.job).ToList(),
                punchList= g3.Select(x=>x.punchList).ToList()
            };
```

Comment: Maybe this will work but we cannot compromise performance.

Comment: I could not run your query to debug it but my aim was to give you a hint and a way to debug first and then works on performance. I also wanted to pretify your code because it has a few issues but I was in rush. I am glad that you have found a way to solve your issue.